# How to show it point after two digit in java?

Tags: android

I am Android developer.I get from web service result 45.0000.i am stored ArrayList.But i want show it point after two digit only.

Example output 45.00 only .Please give me solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat` class to achieve this.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("##.##");
String formate = df.format(value); 
double finalValue = (Double)df.parse(formate) ;
```

Comment: Hi i have implement but no result please see the below in my code

Comment: arrListsubtotal.add(i,rec1.getString("subtotal"));
   String formate = df.format(arrListsubtotal.get(i)); 
   double finalValue = (Double)df.parse(formate) ;
   Log.i(this.toString(), "ValueFinal"+finalValue);

Comment: @Gomathi df.format(arrListsubtotal.get(i)); arrListsubtotal.get(i) should be double not any other object like string..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String.format`, it returns a formatted string using the specified format string and arguments

```
String.format("$%.2f", value);
```

also `String.format` uses your `Locale`

int index = 0;
for (; index < yourList.size (); index++) {
     String tmpvalue = yourList.get(index);
     String conValue = String.format("$%.2f", Float.parse(tmpvalue));
    yourList.set(index, conValue);
    index++;
}

Comment: i am used it arraylist<String> so i can't post argument in value.

Comment: For example i got result from web service .value Rs.2100.0000 i am added ArrayList<String>.add(i,result.getString("amount"));.how to retrive from arraylist?how to convert point after two digit? how to store in again arraylist? Give me solution.

Comment: Example 2100.0000 i want display 2100.00 but i got result this loop apply after 2100.000000